# SSRS - can't remove blank rows

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, duplicates

I've got the following table in sql server 2012 reporting service, where I grouped elements after Time and calculated the average of the group items:

[image]

After using the Hide Duplicate property, I get the following table:

[image]

Now I'm trying to remove the blank rows for hours now, but nothing works. I tried to use the visibility expresion with something like this:

```
=iif(Fields!Menge.Value = "",TRUE,FALSE)
```

but than I get an error, because of an wrong input. (The cell row is a number)

How can I remove this blank rows??

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Previous](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function for the visibility of the Row - something like:

```
=IIf(Previous(Fields!Menge.Value) = Fields!Menge.Value, True, False)
```

You haven't shown how the grouping (if any) is applied in the report, and as such you may have to investigate using the optional `Scope` parameter, but this worked for me in a simple test.

**Edit after comment**

Here's an example on data which is similar to yours:

[image]

And a table with equivalent grouping:

[image]

Set the Row Visibility using the expression above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Table before setting Row Visibility:

[image]

Table after Row Visibility:

[image]

To me this seems to be what you're after.

**Further edit**

OK, if all you're doing in that Details row is applying aggregates (specifically an average in this case) that apply to the group Scope, why not just remove the Details Row entirely and run the aggregates in a group header row?

This way you don't need to worry about showing/hiding rows or hiding duplicates. Your expressions will be the same for every row in the group, so why not just display one row per group?

Your updated table will look something like:

[image]

i.e. removed Details group and row entirely, and added one more group header row.

Which gives the results:

[image]

The expressions are just `=Avg(Fields!Menge.Value)` and `=Avg(Fields!Betrag.Value)` respectively, i.e. the averages of the fields in the respective groups.

Comment: Hi,

I attached a screenshot of my group to my question..

Using your code has doens't work..I applied it to my row cells, but then all elements are displayed..

I think your bracklets are wrong. This seems to be right for me:

=IIf(Previous(Fields!Menge.Value = Fields!Menge.Value), True, False)

But then I just see the first line

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer with a specific example, using the expression I first specified. It looks OK to me, though I suppose I could have the requirements totally wrong.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, but your expression doesn't seems to work for me, which is pretty strange.  I use the following expression to calculate my Value, maybe that's the problem? - Int(Avg(Fields!Menge.Value, "Geschäftsjahrgroup")) - Can you maybe try this for your values and tell me if it's still working?

Comment: One quick question... Is the expression for the `Betrag` column something like `Avg(Fields!Betrag.Value, "Geschäftsjahrgroup")`, i.e. another aggregate in the same Scope as the other expression?

Comment: It's the same aggegation like for Menge.. Int(Avg(Fields!Betrag.Value, "Geschäftsjahrgroup"))

Comment: I've updated the answer - it actually looks like you're just after another group header row. If this is still not working for you, can you please update the question with what you'd expect to see based on my sample dataset?